# Eclipse printing question marks instead of numbers

Tags: c++, eclipse, bit, mask

I apologize in advance if this may seem a silly question to most of you, but I'm relatively new to programming in c++.

Anyways, I was wondering why I am getting some black question mark symbols when trying to print numbers. the code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

uint16_t num1 = 38615;

uint8_t num2 = (num1 & 0XFF);
uint8_t num3 = ((num1 & 0XFF00) >> 8);

cout << num3 << endl; 
cout << num2 <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am doing some tests to learn, What I would like to do is to break "num1" which is 16 bits long into two separate bytes, and print them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The type `uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`. And *all* `char` types are treated as actual printable characters.

If you want to print the *integer* value of a `char` (signed, unsigned, or not specified) then you *must* cast it to a larger integer type:

```
cout << static_cast<unsigned>(num3) << '\n';
```